# node.js - res.WriteHead() ContentType for html with JavaScript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mime-types

I am getting error message `Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Don't you please know, what I should have in `res.WriteHead - Content-Type` instead of `text/html`?

I have following setup of the local server using node.js:

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(error, data){
        if(error){
            res.writeHead(404)
            res.write('Something does not work well')
        }else {
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end()
    })
})

server.listen(port, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log('Something went wrong' + error)
    } else {
        console.log('Everything is working fine on port ' + port)
    }   
})
```

If index.html doesn't contain any javascript, all works fine. The problem is, if it loads some javascript like in this example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='module' src='index.js'></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file looks like this, it is Reactjs:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'


ReactDOM.render(<h1>'Hello world'</h1>,document.getElementById('root'))
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Vaclav

Comment: The browser will download your HTML file, parse it and find a `<script>` tag in it and then will request `index.js`.  You web server will get that request and will send it `index.html` tagged as `text/html` when the browser is expecting a script file.  That's where your problem is.  You need a route for `index.js` that serves the JS file with the right content-type.

Answer (score 4):

The browser will download your HTML file, parse it and find a `<script>` tag in it and then will request `index.js` from your server.

When you web server gets that request it will send it `index.html` tagged as `text/html` when the browser is expecting a script file (because your web server is programmed to send that file and mime type no matter what the incoming request is).  It will also do the same thing when the browser requests `/favicon.ico` or when a search engine requests `/robots.txt`. That's where your problem comes from.

You need to have your web server examine the incoming URL that was requested and branch based on that and handle not only index.html, but also index.js and any other files you may use in your web site.

For two specific files only, you can put an if/else in your server handler that will examine what the http request is and branch accordingly like this:

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 3000;

function sendFile(filename, contentType, callback) {
    fs.readFile(filename, function(error, data) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            res.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            res.write('Something does not work well');
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': contentType });
            res.write(data);
        }
        res.end();
        if (callback) {
            callback(error);
        }
    });
}

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    if (req.url === "/index.js") {
        sendFile('index.js', 'text/javascript');
    } else if (req.url === "/") {
        sendFile('index.html', 'text/html');
    } else {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end();
    }
})

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Something went wrong' + error)
    } else {
        console.log('Everything is working fine on port ' + port)
    }
})
```

In practice for larger projects, most people have a branch of code that handles all static resources automatically by looking in a specific directory (designated for public files) or directory hierarchy for things that match the incoming path requested.  In the Express framework, that would be done with `express.static()`.  There are other libraries for doing that sort of things without Express or you could write your own, though there are some security issues to be aware of when doing so (particularly with `..` segments in the path to make sure an attacker can't explore areas of your server's hard drive that they should not have access to).

Comment: Thank you jfriend00, it helped me much to understand the whole concept! I learned even an aditional stuff, when you provided me with that code.

Comment: @VaclavVlcek - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure here.

Answer (score 2):

Your local web server at this moment respond to every request with an html file with the provided MIME type `text/html`. By adding the `script` tag, you're asking the browser to request for a javascript file which would have a `text/javascript` MIME type. Instead of that, your web server returns the html file with `text/html` MIME type. This is what triggering the encountered error.
You should resolve this error either by rewriting your web server to handle static file request or by using a module like [`serve-static`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static).